# Захват слово под курсором

Tags: delphi

Как завхатить слово под курсором, в любых местах, имя файла, слова в Microsoft Office,или же имя меню который стоит в текущее время под курсором?Аналог программы Lingvo

Answer (score 1):

Есть утилита написанная на дельфи,CopyText

Comment: И где же ее можно найти?

Answer (score 1):

Перейди по этой ссылке (http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/database/5_db.html)
там есть исходник программы называется ABCdic он похож на программу Lingvo...